# How to rotate a UIViewController which is presented as presentModalViewController above a UIViewController inside UINavigationController

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, rotation

I have a `UIViewController` inside `UInavigationController` which is in Portrait mode. Its view has a `UIButton` when tapped presents a custom `UIImagePickerControllerView`'s View (in the same nib file) as `presentModalViewController`. I want only that ViewController to be shown in Landscape mode.

I tried to implement `shouldAutoroateToInterfaceOrientation` method with `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` returning true, but it rotates the parent ViewController, not the  `UIImagePickerController` ViewController which is presented as `presentModalViewController`.
How can I rotate that `UIImagePickerController` ViewController presented as `presentModalViewController` in ios 5 and ios 6? I have searched a lot on internet but no success. Please help.